# Extract Sunday of the Week

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi Im working to extract the next Sunday of the week for any given date in PL/SQL.

I have the following code

```
select TRUNC(to_date('10-07-2016','mm-dd-yyyy'), 'w') + 8 - 1/86400
from dual;
```

This works good when the date itself does not fall on Sunday. When I change the date to 10/8, which is a Sunday, the result would be 10-15-2016, which is the next Sunday, while the desired result is 10-08-2016.

Any thought folks?

Comment: 15th October 2016 is a Saturday? Did you mean you were after Saturdays not Sundays, or should we read those dates as being a day later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT NEXT_DAY(TO_DATE('10-07-2016', 'mm-dd-yyyy')-8, 'SUN') FROM DUAL;

Comment: NEXT_DAY gives the next date after the input date corresponding to the given week day.The subtraction of 8 from original date ensures that the sunday will be of that week itself for all dates.

Comment: sorry i should be more clear on this. Im expecting the sunday of the next week. Say my input is 10/7 and I am expecting 10/8 rather than 10/2.

Comment: Take off the -8 part from the code and it should work fine. Like i said NEXT_DAY function gives the next date in which that week day occurs.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
select TRUNC(to_date('10-09-2016','mm-dd-yyyy'), 'iw')+6 from dual;
```

`'iw'` returns the first day of the ISO week (Monday)